# open drawer from any activity of application in android

Tags: android, slidingmenu

I have sliding menu in my app and I want to open drawer from any activity. Can one help me. I am able to open sliding menu b

> Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
>                                                                                    at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1493)
>                                                                                    at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1511)
>                                                                                    at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStack(FragmentManager.java:591)
>                                                                                    at
>   com.videobankdigital.vmr3.MainActivity_.getBottomFragment(MainActivity_.java:335)
>                                                                                    at
>   com.videobankdigital.vmr3.MainActivity_.switchContent(MainActivity_.java:97)
>                                                                                    at
>   com.videobankdigital.vmr3.SlidingPanelHelper.LeftSliderMenuFragment$1.onItemClick(LeftSliderMenuFragment.java:125)
>                                                                                    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:313)
>                                                                                    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1163)
>                                                                                    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3112)
>                                                                                    at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchUp(AbsListView.java:3913)
>                                                                                    at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3685)
>                                                                                    at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:8725)
>                                                                                    at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2594)
>                                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2305)
>                                                                                    at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2606)
>                                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2320)
>                                                                                    at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2606)
>                                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2320)
>                                                                                    at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2606)
>                                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2320)
>                                                                                    at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2606)
>                                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2320)
>                                                                                    at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2606)
>                                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2320)
>                                                                                    at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2606)
>                                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2320)
>                                                                                    at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2545)
>                                                                                    at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1745)
>                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2834)
>                                                                                    at
>   android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:60)
>                                                                                    at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2506)
>                                                                                    at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8915)
>                                                                                    at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4098)
>                                                                                    at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3961)
>                                                                                    at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3523)
>                                                                                    at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3576)
>                                                                                    at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3542)
>                                                                                    at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3652)
>                                                                                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3550)
>                                                                                    at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3709)
>                                                                                    at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3523)
>                                                                                    at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3576)
>                                                                                    at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3542)
>                                                                                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3550)
>                                                                                    at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3523)
>                                                                                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5795)
>                                                                                    at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5769)
>                                                                                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5740)
>                                                                                    at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5885)
>                                                                                    at
>   android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
>                                                                                    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)

I have used https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu this

Comment: better use navigation drawer

Comment: using navigation drawer can I open drawer from any activity

Comment: nope then you will have to use Fragments

Comment: But I have activity and dont want to use fragemtns

Comment: i suggest to use fragment and maintain stack it will be easy

Comment: Its not possible I have 5-6 activity which has so much functionality

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146750/discussion-between-aditya-vyas-lakhan-and-priyankachauhan).

Comment: can you put some code ? what's on getBottomFragment(MainActivity_.java:335) this line

Comment: getBottomFragment IS USE TO GET FRAGMENT FOR BOTTOM VIEW

Answer (score 1):

Use this sliding menu in one base activity and extend this Activity in other activities wherever You want this sliding menu

Comment: Yes I did it same and its open sliding menu but when we select any slidng menu its crash

Comment: write Onclick method inside the BaseActivity and override that class in other activities for click actions in slider

Comment: I have baseactivity and one main activity which has code for fragemnt transcation. what I am doing starting 3rd activity extends base activity and I can open drawer. in base activity i  have writter code to call main activitu fragment trascation. but current activity is 3rd so its not working

Comment: yes priyanka, now You should write a code for clickable actions inside the baseactivity and override that clickable method inside 3rd activity. try now

Comment: use fragments inside that baseactivity

Comment: Can you give me example ? please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146753/discussion-between-priyankachauhan-and-basha).